# Side effects of flush() OutputStreamWriter to Network

Tags: java, performance, networking, flush

What are the side effects of flushing a OutputStreamWriter which is going to a network socket.

I have a program which calls `out.flush()` after every few bytes. Is there any reason why I should wait until all bytes I need are in the buffer?

Will I get lower transfer rate if I flush too much (more overhead)?

Will this slow down execution of my program (blocking)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you write to a socket, you add between 5 and 15 micro-seconds.  For buffered output, this occurs when you flush() the data.  Note: if you don't have a buffered output, it will be performed on every write() and the flush() won't do anything.

Fortunately the OS expects applications to make more calls than is optimal so the it uses Nagle's algorithm by default to groups portions of the data writing into a larger packets.  Note: not only does the OS do this but some network adapter do this by default too.

In short, don't flush() too often but unless tens of micros-seconds add up to something which matters to you, you might not notice the difference. e.g. if you do 100 flushes you might add a milli-second.

Comment: So the flush won't force Nagle's algorithm to be ignored? That's good to know.

Comment: @JonSkeet socket.setTcpNoDelay(true) should turn off Nagle, but the algorithms used by the OS and Network adapters are adaptive and you often don't see any difference.

Comment: @JonSkeet Of course not. The flush() flushes the application buffer to the TCP buffer. What happens after that is completely independent.

Comment: @EJP: I wouldn't say it's obvious enough to justify "of course not" - generally if I explicitly call `flush()` on something, I expect that flush to heeded as far as possible. For example, a file system may have write buffering as well as the JVM, but I'd expect a flush on a `FileOutputStream` to try to flush the file system buffer too.

Comment: @JonSkeet Then you'd be wrong. It doesn't. FileOutputStream doesn't even have a flush() method of its own, and the Javadoc for the inherited flush() method specifically contradicts your expectation, several times, for example "if the intended destination of this stream is an abstraction provided by the underlying operating system, for example a file, then flushing the stream guarantees only that bytes previously written to the stream are passed to the operating system for writing; it does not guarantee that they are actually written to a physical device such as a disk drive."

Comment: @EJP: Thanks for the heads-up. That feels less than ideal, to be honest :(

Comment: @JonSkeet I disagree. It is documented behaviour, it is Java-specific, and it is orthogonal to operating system facilities such as Nagle, fsync(), etc, which remain accessible where they exist. As a matter of fact there is no TCP mechanism by which an application can force the socket send buffer to be flushed. So building it into Java too wasn't even an available design choice.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to flush unless:

- you want the peer to receive the data as soon as possible
- you've sent a buffered request and you're now going to read the response.

In other cases it is better to allow the buffer, the Nagle algorithm, and the TCP receive window work their magic.

Answer (score 0):

In case of data transfer on network, batching of outputStreamWriter's flush does improve performance.
I observed that single flush of data packet of about 520 bytes was taking around 3 milliseconds.